# ncurses displays characters horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, archlinux

I am writing a simple game in console using ncurses on linux and I have a very odd problem and I cannot find out what's wrong in my code the problem is that when I run my program my screen should  look like this

[image]

which it does but after my `draw()` function runs more than 10 times i get something like this

[image]

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define END endwin();return 0
#define LN 5
#define RN 100

int display [LN][RN] = {
//   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 q w e r t y u 
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//1
    {0,0,'@',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//2
    {0,0,'@',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//3
    {0,0,'@',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},//4
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} //5
};

void setup(){//cr
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < RN ; i++){
        display[LN - 1][i] = 1;
    }
    return;
}


void draw(){  
system("clear");
    for(int i = 0; i < LN ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < RN ; j++){
            if(display[i][j] == 1){
                addch(ACS_HLINE);
            }
            else if(display[i][j] == 0){
                addch(' ');
            }
            else printw("%c",display[i][j]);
        }
        addch('\n');
    }
    refresh();
    system("sleep 0.3");
    return;
}
```

and I'm using arch

Comment: Hi! I would inline your images into your question, but they are way too big for the output to be readable. Could you crop them?

Comment: probably the screen width is less than 100 columns.

Comment: i don't get what you mean

Comment: i mean it works fine with 10 first time that my loop runs

Comment: i update the pics

Comment: `system("clear")` in the middle of a curses program is very suspicious. You generally shouldn't allow anything else to write to the terminal while curses is active. The library's internal model of the screen will get out of sync with the real screen, and then bad stuff happens. Why not use the curses provided `erase()` or `clear()`?

Comment: thanks god you save me this was a project for school that i have to finish  by tomorrow and you just saved my life thank you thank you i love you and  your an angel

Comment: why don't you post your answer

Comment: It's better to copy and past your console output into a `code block` than to use images.

Comment: @jwdonahue in this specific case, I think screenshots are fine. Both because ncurses is all about terminals, not just text, and because broken output could be caused by unusual characters that wouldn't transfer well through copy/paste and web rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[n]curses keeps an internal map of what the screen is supposed to look like. It uses that map to do efficient updates when you call `refresh()`. This only works if the library is exclusively in control of the output to the terminal.

When you do terminal output through some other method, like `system("clear")`, the library no longer has an accurate map of the state of the terminal. The next update sends the escape sequences and printable strings necessary to go from state A to state B, but the terminal is actually in state C, and you end up with something crazy.

There is a curses `erase()` function which clears the screen, which you should use instead. It's equivalent to using a bunch of `addch` calls to write blanks in every position.

There's also a `clear()` function, which does an `erase()` and a `clearok(TRUE)`, which tells the library to throw away its internal map and redraw the whole screen. This can be used to recover from the situation when something bad has happened, corrupting the screen. So, ironically, you could have gotten away with `system("clear")` if you'd done a `clear()` afterward.